# Reemplazar todos los guiones que tengan mis registros en JTable

Tags: java, jtable

Tengo un JTable el cual en la primer columna recibe los registros de la siguiente manera: 555-888-444-99. Quiero hacer que recorra esa columna en especifico y quite los guiones del registro.

Estaba pensando en un for, pero no se como tomar y quitar el guion de los registros.

public void quitarGuiones(){

```
DefaultTableModel dfTD = (DefaultTableModel)   tablaPorFechas.getModel();
for(int i =0; i< dfTD.getRowCount(); i++){

 String columnaRegistros = (String) tablaPorFechas.getValueAt(i, 0);
  //      replaceAll("-", "");
 String quitarGuiones = columnaRegistros ;
 String replaceAll = quitarGuiones.replaceAll("-", "");
  
    }
```

}

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que recorra el Jtable y quite los guiones de los registros en la primer columna?

Comment: Este [artículo](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/java/java-remove-character-from-string/) ¿Podría ser de ayuda?

Comment: puedes hacer uso de `replaceAll("-","")`

Comment: Acabo de editar el metodo usando replaceAll como me comentan pero no realiza nada, creo que no estoy haciendolo correctamente, si me podrian asesorar, muchas gracias

Comment: Ya mire que era lo que me faltaba. muchas gracias por su ayuda!!

Comment: Y entonces, ¿cuál era el problema? Recuerda que el formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_, además de que la pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad.

Comment: Claro que si amigo, en breve comparto la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Era algo muy simple lo que me hacia falta, lo realice de la siguiente manera con el apoyo de sus comentarios y funciono correctamente:

Tome todos los registros de la primer columna y como me comentaron reemplace el guion con el campo en vació y funciono correctamente, despues le hice set para que se reflejara el resultado.

```
public void quitarGuiones(){
           
            int columnaRegistrosINT;
            DefaultTableModel dfTD = (DefaultTableModel) tablaPorFechas.getModel();
            for(int i =0; i< dfTD.getRowCount(); i++){
                
             String columnaRegistros = (String) tablaPorFechas.getValueAt(i, 0);
             String replaceAll = columnaRegistros.replaceAll("-","");
             tablaPorFechas.setValueAt(replaceAll, i, 0);
           
            
                }
        }
```